# How does one recursion in a forloop work?

Tags: c++, recursion

I can't understand this example.I understand the principle of the recursive functions,but in this example i can't understand this recursion in the forloop.
Could someone explain me this example?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int n) 
{
 cout << n;

 for (int i=3; i<n; i=i+1)
    f(n-1); 

 cout << n;
}

int main()
{
  f(5);
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: How about executing it and read what it prints?

Comment: Yes,i executed it,but can't understand the answer.I know what it prints,but can't understand why.It prints: 5433443345.

Comment: try using a debugger and see the output of every steps.

Comment: Also try adding something extra into `cout` like `cout<<"Before: "<<n<<endl;` and after loop  `cout<<"After: "<<n<<endl;`. This will help you understand easily.

Comment: Thank you so much!It helped me!

Answer (score 1):

f(5) will call f(4) twice, i.e. for i=3 and 4

f(4) will call f(3) once, i.e. for i=3

f(3) will not do further calls of f because `3<3` is false

So you have

```
f(5)
  f(4)
    f(3)
  f(4)
    f(3)
```

So now just add the print:

```
f(5)
  5        // on entry
  f(4)     // because i is 3, n is 5
    4      // on entry
    f(3)   // because i is 3, n is 4
      3    // on entry
           // no further call because i is 3, n is 3
      3    // on return
           // no further call because i is 4, n is 4
    4      // on return
  f(4)     // because i is 4, n is 5
    4      // on entry
    f(3)   // because i is 3, n is 4
      3    // on entry
           // no further call because i is 3, n is 3
      3    // on return
           // no further call because i is 4, n is 4
    4      // on return
           // no further call because i is 5, n is 5
  5        // on return
```

so the output is

```
5433443345
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!Finally I understood it! :)

Answer (score -1):

It works the same way recursion works anywhere else.  The function calls itself.  Since it's in a loop it may do so multiple times.

What's causing you confusion?

I would suggest stepping through with a piece of paper and just writing down what the output should be.  Follow the logic all the way through.

Comment: When i come in the forloop and then I must return to the function with f(4),then it prints 4 then again in the forloop and return to f(3),then it prints 3 and when in the forloop(3<3) ..here I am confused..

Comment: I spent 1 hour on this example,and can't understand it..

Comment: @Georgi The function prints `n` twice.  That's why you get two 3s.  Note that 3 is the terminal condition because i is set to three and must be < n to make another recursive call.  If you only spent one hour on it, spend another.  When I started out, stuff like this confused me too but once you get it you'll be slapping your forehead.

Comment: Is there a reason for this answer to be downvoted? I'm confused. It gives good advices.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!It helped me!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry this is in java and not in C but I already had this typed up. 
This is probably the most understandable recursive algorithm in my opinion.
the factorial of 5 is 120 for reference.

```
    1. run through the code
    2. write down the value of variables at each point 
    3. check the output with the correct answer
```

once you understand this simpler recursive algorithm run through your convoluted example again and see if it makes a little more sense.

**Java Example:**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(fact(5));
}

public static int fact(int n){
    if(n < 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return n*fact(n-1);
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps!